# Apache mod_rewrite: redirecting subdomains to the HTTPS login page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to accomplish this:

`http://subdomain.server.com/` should redirect to `https://secure.server.com/login?subdomain`, but `http://subdomain.server.com/any-other-page` should pass through as-is.

Can I accomplish this in the `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=secure
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://secure.example.com/login?%1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch ^/?$ https://secure.server.com/login?subdomain
```